# How to control accessing file by anonymous users in YII

Tags: yii

We have created a site in Yii Framework, In that we have some hrlp document files which is stored in root folder. the issue is anonymous users are able to access the files. it should be access only if session is there.

Kindly help me fix this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First want i will do is move the file or at least change the name of it and then something like this :

```
public function actionHelp() {
    $url = Yii::app()->getBasePath() .'/../text.txt';
    if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
        $this->renderFile($url);
    }
}
```